# eslint ignores files included via `importScripts`

Tags: eslint, babel-eslint

I'm working on webextension and have `service_worker.js` with the following code:

```js
importScripts("debug.js")
debug.log("blah");
```

The `debug.js` contains:

```js
const debug = console.bind(console);
```

eslint gives error:

```
'debug' is not defined. eslint(no-undef)`
```

Pointing at the second line of `service_worker.js`

In `.eslintrc.json` I have this:

```
  "env": {
      "es6": true,
      "serviceworker": true,
      "webextensions": true
  },
```

So it understands that it's a service worker and what `importScripts()` is, but it ignores data from included files...
Any ideas how to fix this issue?